# Ionic 2 (3) does not add os specific classes

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have external module which I use in my app.

The shared module header

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import {Nav} from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
    selector: 'hg-page-header',
    template: `
        <ion-header>
            <ion-navbar [class]="navbarClass">
                <button ion-button menuToggle end *ngIf="menuToggleRight">
                    <ion-icon [name]="iconName"></ion-icon>
                </button>
                <button ion-button menuToggle *ngIf="!menuToggleRight">
                    <ion-icon [name]="iconName"></ion-icon>
                </button>
                <ion-title [class]="navbarTitleClass">{{ title | translate}}</ion-title>
            </ion-navbar>
        </ion-header>
    `
})
export class PageHeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private ngUnSubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
    @Input() navbarClass: string;
    @Input() navbarTitleClass: string;
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() iconName: string;
    @Input() menuToggleRight: boolean;

    constructor() {
    }

    private setListeners(): void {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.setListeners();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngUnSubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnSubscribe.complete();
    }
}
```

The external module.ts file

```
import {NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {IonicModule} from 'ionic-angular';

import {ISharedModuleConfig} from './models/shared-config.model';
import {PageHeaderComponent} from './components/page-header/page-header.component';
import {MenuComponent} from './components/menu/menu.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        //Component
        PageHeaderComponent,
        MenuComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
    ],
    exports: [
        //Component
        PageHeaderComponent,
        MenuComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})

export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(sharedModuleConfig: ISharedModuleConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [
                {provide: 'ISharedModuleConfig', useValue: sharedModuleConfig}
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

How I use it

```
<hg-page-header *ngIf="findMenuItemByComponent(nav?.getActive()?.component)?.showMainMenu" [iconName]="'menu'"
                [navbarClass]="'toolbar toolbar-ios toolbar-md'" [navbarTitleClass]="'title title-ios title-md'"
                [title]="nav?.getActive()?.component.name" [menuToggleRight]="true"></hg-page-header>
```

When I pass the classes as the example above, it works and everything is styled and all the ionic styling is in palce.

But when I remove the classes from the html and the `[class]="variable"` - ionic does not add it by itself.

The problematic items are `ion-navbar` and `ion-title`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with help from a friend

The `[class]` directive WILL OVERRIDE the default classes which are added by ionic